# Git on Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion)

Tags: git, macos, osx-lion

I just upgraded my Mac to [Mac OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion), and now Git is gone:

```
$ git
-bash: git: command not found
```

How can I get Git back?

Comment: Well, where was it? How did you install it originally? Is the directory where it was still in your `PATH`?

Comment: Here exactly the same question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/git-not-found-after-installing-os-x-lion

Comment: You closed it yet it's exactly on topic based on the link you posted in the closed notice: "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: I had the same problem but instead of an upgrade, i used the migration assistant to load a new machine based on my old one. xcode was there, but the path to git was no longer found. So I added it to my path as outlined below.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The default install location is */usr/local*, so add this to your *~/.bash_profile* file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/
```

Then run `source ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming and I understand you have to add `PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH` to your ~/.bash_profile but I can't seem to find (or access .bash_profile). I tried typing `~/.bash_profile` in Terminal but got "Permission denied." I don't otherwise know how to access the .bash_profile (I tried using sudo but it's either not possible or I'm using the wrong sudo commands).

I would greatly appreciate help in updating/accessing ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Figured it out...since the file was locked I couldn't open it through Terminal so I had to make my hidden files visible then manually open .bash_profile in Finder and add the line of code to make it work. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Git does not ship with the base OS X Lion install, you need to install X Code, not all of it if you don't want it, of course.  See the helpful note below.

Comment: on some systems (eg. mine) `~/.bash_profile` might be just `~/.profile`

Comment: @kritzikratzi he's talking about Lion not other systems.

Comment: i hate to reply to a response of a response, anyways: yes, i can read. yes, i have lion. yes, on my computer the file was ~/.profile;  ~/.bash_profile doesn't even exist.

Comment: With latest Mountain Lion, you download and install Xcode from the App Store. In Xcode 4.3, git and 11MB of other command line tools are in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin. (There's also an option to install Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tools (154.6 MB), I'm not sure what that gives you.

Comment: @kritzikratzi, read `man bash`: "looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,  and ~/.profile,  in  that  order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists..." Only use ~/.profile if you use other bash-compatible shells and want the same settings in all.

Comment: @skierpage
yea, i guess that's the behavior you want with path variables :)  btw., i'm using zsh, that would also explain the lack of a .bash_profile

Comment: This worked to fix my mountain lion install, I love you. Thank you so much.

Comment: make sure you have downloaded the Xcode Command Line Tools before trying the above (at least for Mountain Lion).

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote anyway but just to be clear the path on Mountain Lion is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin as mentioned by @skierpage

Answer (score 15):

If you do not want to install Xcode and/or [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts)/[Fink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fink_(software))/[Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)), you could always use the standalone installer: https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/

Comment: They didn't have a version for Lion but I used the latest for Snow Leopard and it installed it at /usr/local/git/bin/git. So far so good. :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to find where the Git executable is and then add the folder to the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable in file *.bash_profile*.

Using terminal:

1. Search for Git:

   ```
    sudo find / -name git
   ```
2. Edit the *.bash_profile* file. Add:

   ```
    PATH="<Directory of Git>:$PATH"
   ```

Git is back :-)

Anyway, I suggest you to install Git using [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts). In this way you can easily upgrade your Git instance to the newest release.

Comment: when I entered step one, I got this error "find: git: No such file or directory"

Comment: it seems that you don't have git installed in your system

Comment: @JGallardo The find 'expression' above was broken.  It was just using "find / git" but should be "find / -name git".  I've edited the answer to be more compatible with all find versions (in case it worked for others already, but I doubt it?)

Comment: I would had `git's directory` after the path in order to avoid eventual conflicts

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of points to this answer.

Firstly, you don't need to install Xcode. The Git installer works perfectly well. However, if you want to use Git from within Xcode - it expects to find an installation under /usr/local/bin. If you have your own Git installed elsewhere - I've got [a script](https://gist.github.com/774277) that fixes this.

Second is to do with the path. My Git path used to be kept under `/etc/paths.d/` However, a [Mac OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) install overwrites the contents of this folder and the `/etc/paths` file as well. That's what happened to me and I got the same error. Recreating the path file fixed the problem.

Comment: After upgrading to Lion, you can download XCode 4.1 for free from the Mac App Store and it fixes this as well.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was obvious, but good clarification b/c it might not be to some.

Comment: With Xcode 4.3 under Lion, I find `git` $not$ at `/usr/local/bin` but rather at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 4):

It's part of [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). You'll need to reinstall the developer tools.

Comment: Thanks!  I naively thought it shipped with the base install.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)...

Comment: You'll need to install the developer tools to use either of these, and Xcode 4.x comes with git already.

Comment: I tried installing MacPorts but it gave me an error that it could not install to this disk. I am trying to install on a work computer.