# How to run jenkins build with sudo permission?

Tags: linux, jenkins

For some reason jenkins cannot execute sudo related command when the build is invoked from the "Build now" button on the browser or when triggered by a git push. I get errors like

"jenkins is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

However I ssh into the instance and do

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo jenkins
```

I verified it by

```
groups jenkins
```

where the output is

```
jenkins : jenkins sudo
```

I also attempted to execute the command myself in the console and it works without a problem

```
su jenkins
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myrepo/build/
sudo make install
```

I also doubled checked

```
sudo visudo
```

and there is

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to run jenkins as sudo?

Comment: @Cyclone one repo depends on the library from another repo, if will be nice if the libraries will be updated instantly on the git push. I could do a cronjob that does a daily pull and sudo make install but the update won't be instant

Comment: Well, in that case there should be not reason to run jenkins as root, you just need to give the desired access to git to jenkins?

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639501/jenkins-could-not-run-git

Comment: @Cyclone the libraries need to be installed to /usr/local/lib and the headers to /usr/local/include in order to successfully link it for the other repo. Just like how open source code like OpenCV and PCL install their library to the system