# Jenkins on windows -integrate with Git

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set up Jenkins runnning on windows connected to gitlab. Git will checkout a jenkinsfile that it will run on a Linux slave. Pipeline code is basic echo commands.
I do not want to manually keep putting pipeline code inside my jobs.

- SSH keys have been generated via gitbash and synched with git. Pull works on gitbash.
- Git path has been added in global env variables of Jenkins.
- I already ran git confit ssl verify off
- Checkout is working

The pipeline is showing the below.. what am I missing on my Jenkins env on windows ?
———-

[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential c36c23b2-ea6e-4bc6-afff-dfbe559198e4
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

————
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /root/jenkins/workspace/CICD_2104

Comment: Jenkins over windows throws unexpected errors. Is it mandatory windows? Are the technologies to be built: c# or something that windows is required?

Comment: I suspect some env issue in my Linux slave ?[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential c36c23b2-ea6e-4bc6-afff-dfbe559198e4
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /root/jenkins/workspace/CICD_2104
       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Global Credential valid for your repository then, its only be keen on path of .jenkinsfile/.groovy  you are providing in your pipeline.

Problem could be in
1.

`Manage Jenkins` --> `Global Tool Configuration` settings.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639501/jenkins-could-not-run-git/42703766) will also help to guide with Global Tool Configuration setting.

Or
2. May be in your pipeline --> Script path is wrong.

If your repository is
`gitlab.domain.com:userid/playground.git`

then root folder for Script path must playground and script path can be sub folder of playground.

e.g. My Jenkins file is structured like `playground/Sample/ParallelPipeline.Jenkinsfile`.

In this case script path will be `Sample/ParallelPipeline.Jenkinsfile`

[image]

Here is a [LINK](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/customer-success/demo-systems/tutorials/integrations/create-jenkins-pipeline/) for complete process of configuring Jenkinsfile with Gitlab

Comment: Ok. So I  have one branch 2104. I juts updated my Jenkins file to run in master node and added a bat instead of sh.. it worked good on windows as long as I specified to build master in my pipeline.  Maine issue is when I try running the build for branch 2104 that will run it on my Linux slave nodes. That is where it fails ? .. would I need to configure git connectivity on Linux slave too ?  Pipeline code for 2104 has sh ‘’

Comment: That looks another problem no need to configure git connectivity on Linux slave, usually it should not matter if you run on Branch or Master, But you can defined agent / node label as your windows machine, in this way pipeline will be executed on windows instead of Linux, hope this helps.