# Git, Tower, and Sourcetree

Tags: macos, git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-tower

I'm trying out both Tower and Sourcetree GUIs on my Mac and I have two very basic questions:

- Do either of these GUIs install the Git executables or do they *use* the Git installed on my Mac?
- Where would Git be installed on my Mac? At the command prompt I've typed "which git", but it clearly isn't in the PATH so no luck with that. It's weird because I swear it *used* to be in the PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Found in the [Tower FAQ](http://www.git-tower.com/support/faq.html):

> As Tower comes with a fully functional Git binary, you don't have to
> install Git on your system to use Tower. If you also want to use Git
> on the command line, though, we recommend you use the OS X installer or
> MacPorts (if present on your system).

- As for Sourcetree, I believe it requires Git to be preinstalled on your machine.
- If you recently upgraded to [OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion), check this out:
  *[Git on Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810059/git-on-mac-os-x-lion)*

Comment: Thanks for the completion of my answer ;) Just a minor point : try to install through brew instead of port, usually versions are more up to date.

Comment: Well the strangest thing is I have Lion. Git WAS installed and in the PATH but it isn't anymore and it's not in any of the locations suggested in the aforementioned thread. I suspect, but don't know, that this may have coincided with the install of XCode 4.3.2 (which didn't replace XCode 4.2.1).

Comment: Ok, after digging around I found git in /Developer/usr/bin. I guess I'll add this to the path and use this across XCode, command line, and SourceTree.  (reference link: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/18472)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Tower, but you can see in Sourcetree's settings that it can either use the system Git (I think a version of Git is already embedded in Mac OS X) or a version embedded within the Sourcetree application.

On my system `which git` gives me:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

It should be in the path, if you didn't change anything.

Comment: I've looked in all the standard places but can't find it. I think it may have been undone by the latest XCode install (see my comment to @DennisJaamann)